# Server Online/Offline script for multiple IP's

Tags: php, ping, offline

I was just looking for php script to check server Online Or OFfline for my website.. On one forum I found the following script:

```
<?php
    /* our simple php ping function */
    function ping($host)
    {
            exec(sprintf('ping -c 1 -W 5 %s', escapeshellarg($host)), $res, $rval);
            return $rval === 0;
    }

    /* check if the host is up
            $host can also be an ip address */
    $host = 'XX.XX.XX.XX';
    $up = ping($host);

    /* optionally display either a red or green image to signify the server status */
    if ($up) {
    echo 'Online';
} else {
    echo 'Offline';
}
    ?>
```

I Just wanna know how to ping multiple IP's in same script? also how to add online since counter... ?  Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array of IP and iterate it:

```
$ips = array('XX.XX.XX.XX',
             'XX.XX.XX.XX',
             'XX.XX.XX.XX');
foreach($ips as $ip)
{
    if (ping($ip))
        echo $ip.' Online';
    else
        echo $ip.' Offline';
}
```

Comment: Dint work... I tried this:  <?php

    /* our simple php ping function */
    function ping($host)
    {
            exec(sprintf('ping -c 1 -W 5 %s', escapeshellarg($host)), $res, $rval);
            return $rval === 0;
    }

    /* check if the host is up
            $host can also be an ip address */
    $host =  array(130.211.188.132,74.125.136.95,37.58.73.184);
foreach($host as $ip)

{
    if (ping($ip))
        echo $ip.' Online';
    else
        echo $ip.' Offline';
}
 
 

    ?>

Comment: Don't forget the quotes in the array

Comment: Cant we just ping 3 ips and show one result either online or offline .. Like all 3 working means online.. 1 not working means unstable .. and nun then offline?